# How do I show the new form at the current position of the mouse cursor?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code:

```
private void hsMagnfier_OnMouseDown(object sender)
{
    int x = mLastCursorPosition.X;
    int y = mLastCursorPosition.Y;
    MagnifierForm magnifier = new MagnifierForm(mConfiguration, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);//mLastCursorPosition);
    magnifier.Show();
}
```

This code above is in a `Form` which I can drag over the screen.

Then when I click on an icon it's doing the `magnifier.Show();` and the magnifier form is shown up where the mouse current position is.

But if I click on it again so now the position of the new form the magnifier is in my `Form1` center. And not where the mouse current position as in the first time.

This is the `MagnifierForm` code maybe first time it's in the current mouse position but in the next time/s it's in the center of `Form1` ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ScreenVideoRecorder
{
    public partial class MagnifierForm : Form
    {

        public MagnifierForm(Configuration configuration, Point startPoint)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //--- My Init ---
            mConfiguration = configuration;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

            ShowInTaskbar = mConfiguration.ShowInTaskbar;
            TopMost = mConfiguration.TopMostWindow;
            Width = mConfiguration.MagnifierWidth;
            Height = mConfiguration.MagnifierHeight;

            // Make the window (the form) circular
            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            gp.AddEllipse(ClientRectangle);
            Region = new Region(gp);

            mImageMagnifier = Properties.Resources.magnifierGlass;

            mTimer = new Timer();
            mTimer.Enabled = true;
            mTimer.Interval = 20;
            mTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(HandleTimer);

            mScreenImage = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                     Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

            mStartPoint = startPoint;
            mTargetPoint = startPoint;

            if (mConfiguration.ShowInTaskbar)
                ShowInTaskbar = true;
            else
                ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }

        protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
        {
            RepositionAndShow();
        }

        private delegate void RepositionAndShowDelegate();

        private void RepositionAndShow()
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                Invoke(new RepositionAndShowDelegate(RepositionAndShow));
            }
            else
            {
                // Capture the screen image now!
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(mScreenImage);
                g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(mScreenImage.Width, mScreenImage.Height));
                g.Dispose();                

                if (mConfiguration.HideMouseCursor)
                    Cursor.Hide();
                else
                    Cursor = Cursors.Cross;

                Capture = true;

                if (mConfiguration.RememberLastPoint)
                {
                    mCurrentPoint = mLastMagnifierPosition;
                    Cursor.Position = mLastMagnifierPosition;
                    Left = (int)mCurrentPoint.X - Width / 2;
                    Top = (int)mCurrentPoint.Y - Height / 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    mCurrentPoint = Cursor.Position;
                }
                Show();
            }
        }

        void HandleTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float dx = mConfiguration.SpeedFactor * (mTargetPoint.X - mCurrentPoint.X);
            float dy = mConfiguration.SpeedFactor * (mTargetPoint.Y - mCurrentPoint.Y);

            if (mFirstTime)
            {
                mFirstTime = false;

                mCurrentPoint.X = mTargetPoint.X;
                mCurrentPoint.Y = mTargetPoint.Y;

                Left = (int)mCurrentPoint.X - Width / 2;
                Top = (int)mCurrentPoint.Y - Height / 2;

                return;
            }

            mCurrentPoint.X += dx;
            mCurrentPoint.Y += dy;

            if (Math.Abs(dx) < 1 && Math.Abs(dy) < 1)
            {
                mTimer.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Update location
                Left = (int)mCurrentPoint.X - Width / 2;
                Top = (int)mCurrentPoint.Y - Height / 2;
                mLastMagnifierPosition = new Point((int)mCurrentPoint.X, (int)mCurrentPoint.Y);
            }

            Refresh();
        }


        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mOffset = new Point(Width / 2 - e.X, Height / 2 - e.Y);
            mCurrentPoint = PointToScreen(new Point(e.X + mOffset.X, e.Y + mOffset.Y));
            mTargetPoint = mCurrentPoint;
            mTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mConfiguration.CloseOnMouseUp)
            {
                Close();
                mScreenImage.Dispose();
            }

            Cursor.Show();
            Cursor.Position = mStartPoint;            
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                mTargetPoint = PointToScreen(new Point(e.X + mOffset.X, e.Y + mOffset.Y));
                mTimer.Enabled = true;
            } 
        }

        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mConfiguration.DoubleBuffered)
            {
                // Do not paint background (required for double buffering)!
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnPaintBackground(e);
            }
        }

        protected override void  OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mBufferImage == null)
            {
                mBufferImage = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
            }
            Graphics bufferGrf = Graphics.FromImage(mBufferImage);

            Graphics g;

            if (mConfiguration.DoubleBuffered)
            {
                g = bufferGrf;
            }
            else
            {
                g = e.Graphics;
            }

            if (mScreenImage != null)
            {
                Rectangle dest = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
                int w = (int)(Width / mConfiguration.ZoomFactor);
                int h = (int)(Height / mConfiguration.ZoomFactor);
                int x = Left - w / 2 + Width / 2;
                int y = Top - h / 2 + Height / 2;

                g.DrawImage(
                    mScreenImage,
                    dest,
                    x, y,
                    w, h,
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            if (mImageMagnifier != null)
            {
                g.DrawImage(mImageMagnifier, 0, 0, Width, Height);
            }

            if (mConfiguration.DoubleBuffered)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(mBufferImage, 0, 0, Width, Height);
            }      
        }


        //--- Data Members ---
        #region Data Members
        private Timer mTimer;
        private Configuration mConfiguration;
        private Image mImageMagnifier;
        private Image mBufferImage = null;
        private Image mScreenImage = null;
        private Point mStartPoint;
        private PointF mTargetPoint;
        private PointF mCurrentPoint;
        private Point mOffset;
        private bool mFirstTime = true;
        private static Point mLastMagnifierPosition = Cursor.Position;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The first time the new Form the magnifier is shown up where my mouse cursour is. 
The next time i click on it's showing the magnifier form in the center of Form1 and not where the mouse cursour is.

Why is that ? When i clikc on the icon again it's still doing the

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position
```

Again. Strange.

Comment: Checked again first time it's showing the magnifier form in the current position of the mouse cursour but next time/s it's showing the new magnifier form in the position the magnifier form was last time. If i moved the magnifier form around the screen and left it somewhere next time i will show the magnifier again it will be in the last place i left it and not where the mouse cursour is. I checked again each time i click to show the magnifier form it's doing the System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position but show it in the last place it was and not where the mouse cursour is.

Comment: Something is preventing from the magnifier form to be shown where the mouse cursour is currently and make it to show it where the magnifier was last time. Something need to be reseted maybe it's something with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found that the part that doing it is here in the Magnifier form:

```
mConfiguration.RememberLastPoint = false;
if (mConfiguration.RememberLastPoint)
{
    mCurrentPoint = mLastMagnifierPosition;
    Cursor.Position = mLastMagnifierPosition;
    Left = (int)mCurrentPoint.X - Width / 2;
    Top = (int)mCurrentPoint.Y - Height / 2;
}
else
{
    mCurrentPoint = Cursor.Position;
}
```

So I added for now the line: `mConfiguration.RememberLastPoint = false;` which did the job for now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have two forms - `Master` and `Child`

If you are calling Child from Master on `MouseUp` event(for example), write the code in `MouseUp` event of `Master` form

```
ChildForm obj=new ChildForm();
obj.pntLocation = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
obj.ShowDialog();
```

Declare a variable inside the Child for location

```
public Point pntLocation;
```

Now set location inside the `Form_Load` of `Child`

```
this.Location = pntLocation;
```